# Adding 'Share on Twitter' functionality on Django-powered site

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, twitter, share

I'm trying to add 'Share on Twitter' functionality on one of the pages of my Django-powered site. Here's the relevant portion of link_page.html:

```
<a class="tweet_link metaSpacing" data-link_id={{ link.id }}>Share on Twitter</a>
```

Here's the JavaScript portion responsible for listening for events:

```
// tweet_link
$('.tweet_link').click(function(e){
    link_id = $(this).attr('data-link_id');
    var target = $(this);
    tweetLink(target);
});

function tweetLink(t){
    link_id = t.attr('data-link_id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: { "link_id": link_id, "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrfmiddlewaretoken},
        url: "/tweet_link",
    });     
};
```

In Django I added the following line at the end of the urls.py:

```
url(r'^tweet_link/?$', 'portnoy.views.tweet_link'),
```

And here's the Django view itself:

```
# tweet the link
def tweet_link(request):
    c = RequestContext(request)
    twitter = Twython(
        twitter_token = TWITTER_KEY,
        twitter_secret = TWITTER_SECRET,
        oauth_token = request.session['request_token']['oauth_token'],
        oauth_token_secret = request.session['request_token']['oauth_token_secret']
    )
    twitter.updateStatus(status="See how easy this was?")
    return HttpResponse('')
```

However, what happens when I click on the 'Share on Twitter' link, I get this error on Chrome Console:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/tweet_link 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url shouldn't have a `?` in it:

```
url(r'^tweet_link/$', 'portnoy.views.tweet_link'),
```

You know that you can simply launch a link with this URL to tweet something:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=webclient&text=d+twitter+msg+goes+here
```